# Curl in combinaties wit variables

Tags: bash, curl

In My bash file i use curl
The line bellow works like a charm

```
curl -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" --ftp-create-dirs "ftp://191.158.2.04/$DESTDIRNAS/$TIMESTAMP/"
```

But when i make a variable of the ip adres it dont work anymore

```
SERVER = "191.162.2.04"

curl -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" --ftp-create-dirs "ftp://$SERVER/$DESTDIRNAS/$TIMESTAMP/"
```

Sorry i wil give some more info
When i run the script the script it does hang on this line.
I get a promt > but cannot used it. I must compleet reset putty to go on.

SpelChek give my this output.
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 10:
SERVER="191.162.2.04"             # IP of NAS, used for ftp
^-- SC2034 (warning): SERVER appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

$

Comment: generally speaking ... *`it dont work anymore`* ... tells us nothing; does it generate an error? does it generate the wrong output (and if so, *what* output does it generate)? does it hang? something else? update the question with additional details of what you mean by *`it dont work anymore`*; in the meantime, consider cutting-n-pasting your code (plus the appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), make the recommended code changes, and if you still have problems then update the question with your latest code plus details of your (new) issue

Comment: Is `SERVER = "191.158.2.04"` literally the command you used? That tries to invoke a command called `SERVER` with arguments `=` and `191.158.2.04`. Did you not see an error message `SERVER: command not found`?

Comment: Run the code through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find the problem.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds *many* common problems (and some not so common problems) in shell code.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to replace this line:

```
SERVER = "191.158.2.04"
```

with:

```
SERVER="191.158.2.04"
```

Suggesting to debug your code with `set -x` and `set +x` to view the expanded command:

```
SERVER="191.158.2.04"
set -x #debug analysis start
curl -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" --ftp-create-dirs "ftp://$SERVER/$DESTDIRNAS/$TIMESTAMP/"
set +x #debug analysis end
```